# console.log the data from json url using http get

Tags: typescript

I have printed the data in html from https://api.github.com/repositories/19438/commits
.html

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-commitsapi',
  templateUrl: './commitsapi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./commitsapi.component.css']
})
export class CommitsapiComponent implements OnInit {
  commitdata: Object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/repositories/19438/commits',)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.commitdata = res;
        console.log(res);
        //console.log("url: " + res.avatar_url);
      console.log("name: " + res.commit.author.name);
      console.log("date: " + res.commit.author.date);

      })
  }
}
```

```html
<pre>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div *ngFor="let item of commitdata">
  <img src={{item.author.avatar_url}}>
  <h4><b>ID :</b> {{item.author.id}} </h4>
  <h4><b>Name :</b> {{item.commit.author.name}} </h4>
  <h4><b>Email :</b> {{item.commit.author.email}} </h4>
  <h4><b>Date :</b> {{item.commit.author.date | date : 'long'}} </h4>
  <hr>
</div>
</pre>
```

Now I'm trying to console log the data using typescript from  https://api.github.com/repositories/19438/commits  and output should be only selected objects from the array as I have done using html.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is an Array. In template you iterate the array with the `*ngIf`, but an iteration is missing in the subscription callback. You could do that:

```
res.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```